# How does the equation equal the system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how $x'' + (2 + 3x^2)x' + x = 0$ can be converted to 
$x'=y-x^3$ and $y'=-x+2x^3-2y$. The standard way of converting a second order ode to a system of first order odes didn't work... thanks.

Comment: Just let $y=x'+x^3$?

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I will give that a try

Comment: @KennyLau if I let $y=x'+x^3$ then the $y'=x''+3x^2x'$ right? I can't see what to do next

Comment: Use $x''+(2+3x^2)x'+x=0$ (subtract this from that)

Comment: I am sorry I am still not seeing this...